# How to find highest volume level of a WAV file using C++

Tags: c++, audio, wav, volume, sample-data

I want to get the value of the highest volume level of a WAV-file by using C++ (library libsndfile)? Any suggestions on how to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply find the highest single sample value (Peak) among the absolute values of the samples in the sample buffer(s). This takes the *general* form:

```
t_sample PeakAmplitude(const t_sample* const buffer, const size_t& count) {
  t_sample highest(0);
  for (size_t idx(0); idx < count; ++idx) {
    // or fabs if fp
    highest = std::max(highest, abs(buffer[idx]));
  }
  return highest;
}
```

To get averages, you can use RMS functions. Illustration:

```
t_sample RMSAmplitude(const t_sample* const buffer, const size_t& count) {
  t_sample s2(0);
  for (size_t idx(0); idx < count; ++idx) {
    // mind your sample types and ranges
    s2 += buffer[idx] * buffer[idx];
  }
  return sqrt(s2 / static_cast<double>(count));
}
```

RMS calculations are closer to human perception than Peak.

To go even deeper into human perception, you can employ [Weighing Filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighting_filter).

Comment: I'm not familiar with libsndfile, but is this RMS? If you're just returning the max sample value, this number may not correspond to volume as perceived by a human.

Comment: @amwinter the original showed Peak - i just expanded the answer. cheers